# Search Results Page error if less than 20 search results

Tags: component, joomla-3.4, search

I have a strange bug that I can not seem to wrap my head around.

Using the default Joomla Search function, whenever I have either an empty results page (on first load) or less than 20 results for a particular keyword, the footer appears in the middle of the page as if it is not recognizing the search results containing div.

However, if I search for a keyword and the results are greater than 20, the page displays properly.

Also... if I limit the search page results to just 5 for instance and there are more than 5 results, then the page displays normally.

Does the presence of the the bottom page nav affect it somehow?

I have included screen shots.

Here is the site (UN and PW is required):

http://staging.suntechmed.net/search

User Name: suntech
Password: airportblvd

If you want to search for terms, terms like "hypertension" display properly but "white" doesn't.

Please help! Thank you!

[image: An image of the display error when less than 20 results are returned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your containing div has the class .search and you give that class in custom.css a height of 55px. I assume it's because you want to fit the search button into the main navi.

If you want only your search button in the main navi to have a height of 55px use this rule:

```
.head-search .search {
    height: 55px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me :) The suggestions listed below by others also worked but I went with this suggestion because it corrected a mistake I had made when trying to target only the search class in the top nav. Well done! I knew I had screwed something up :) I tried to up-vote your answer but I'm too much if a noob so I don't think it counts. - Cheers

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of file `/templates/purity_iii/css/custom.css` add selector

```
.search-results {   
float:left;  
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use ID selectors in CSS

Comment: simply use `.search form { float: left }`. No need to use the ID selector or `!important`

Comment: `.search-results` doesn't appear to exist. Not sure where you got this from either ;)

Comment: <dl class="search-results"> /t3-assets/dev/templates.purity_iii.less.joomla.less.css Line 527